# How to ftp a file over to a server from PhoneGap/webapp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, ajax, cordova

Is it possible to connect to a server and FTP a file from within PhoneGap application? Basically I suppose - is there a way to open an FTP connection with Ajax/JQuery somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to FTP a file from PhoneGap however they do provide an API for transferring a file to a server using HTTP multipart encoding:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

You would need a script on the server in your chosen technology to receive the file however you should then be able to do whatever you like with it, including move it to the directory you are trying to FTP to

Answer (score 0):

Ftp program for phone gap is here please see this bellow link.

https://github.com/macdonst/FtpClient