# How to download a file from FTP and store it locally with Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, ftp, cordova-plugins

I'm struggling for some days to do that. Without success.

I've found two ways that I think reasonably to follow:

**1: Plugin cordova-sftp-plugin.**

I see that it is writted to deal with 'secure ftp', but why wouldn't work in an ordinary non secure ftp? Nothing was metioned about it.

I've tried so, applying the 'Use Example' from the official page, the code fells in the success callback function, but when I list the local directory, nothing was changed! It gives me no clue about what goes wrong! In true, the software does not detect nothing wrong.

Before the previous steps, I did not forget to precautionally install and enable the 'cordova-plugin-file', 'cordova-plugin-file-transfer' and 'cordova-plugin-network-information' and to add the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> in the AndroidManifest.xml. Tryied to save files in cordova.file.externalRootDirectory and cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + "/Downloads/. Nothing worked.

**2. The macdonst FtpClient plugin.**

Searching for my issue, one of the first pages that appears is [How to ftp a file over to a server from PhoneGap/webapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249645/how-to-ftp-a-file-over-to-a-server-from-phonegap-webapp), and beyond some further search I've found another one in a relatively old post mentioned the successful use this plugin in a Cordova application. So I can consider this plugin as a stable choice.

The problem with this method comes earlier: I coundn't even build the application after a manual installation proccess. May it is a problem in the manual installation proccess.

The official plugin documentation teachs to install it in a PhoneGap application, and not a Cordova. The steps was not replicable to Cordova, due to some differences in paths and configuration, and some others links also supports the plugin installation solely in Phonegap, not Cordova.

I also tryied follow the steps in the http://antonylees.blogspot.com.br/2015/01/how-to-manually-add-cordova-plugins-to.html and [Manually install Device plugin (and others) into cordova 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778032/manually-install-device-plugin-and-others-into-cordova-3-0) to manually add the plugin. The steps in the first link also was not well replicable, and although the second one are more straitfoward, also does not solved the issue.

Building it gives me a java error compilation. The first error output (what uses to cause all the following errors are):

```
E:\danilo\Documentos\projetos_cordova\ftpDownload3\platforms\android\src\com\phonegap\plugins\ftpclient\FtpClient.java:27: 
error: package org.apache.cordova.api does not exist
import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
```

Very strange. May I have to search for the org.apache.cordova.api jar file and put in the lib folder? Also, I did not forget to put the commons-net-2.2.jar in the project libs folder.

Can anyone have some suggestion to succeed this? I just want to download a file through ftp protocol and save locally and so, if there's an alternative method to succeed, it will be appreciated too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any solution for downloading file via ftp path from browser?